# Usar group_by en una función

Tags: r

Tengo el siguiente df y quiero agruparlo por modelo y color

```
d1=data.frame(Modelo = sample(c("ModeloA","ModeloB","ModeloC","ModeloD"), 20, replace=TRUE),
              Color = sample(c("ColorA","ColorB","ColorC"), 20, replace=TRUE),
              Distancia = sample(100:300, 20, replace=TRUE),
              Id=1:20)
    
    
d1 %>%  
  group_by(Modelo,Color) %>% 
  summarise(n= n())
```

Ahora supongamos que tengo una función y en cierto momento el usuario tiene que indicar las columnas a agrupar:

```
agrupar <- function(col){
           d1 %>%  
           group_by(col) %>% 
           summarise(n= n())
           }

agrupar(c("Modelo","Color"))
```

Pero group_by no reconoce col.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tidyverse/dplyr` hace uso muy intenso de lo que se conoce como [evaluación no estándar](https://pmoracho.github.io/blog/2019/02/04/Evaluacion-no-estandar-en-R/) o **NSE**, lo que permite (entre otras cosas) que escribas los nombres de columnas sin las comillas. Esto es sin duda muy cómodo, pero plantea dificultades a la hora de usar rutinas que hacen uso de **NSE** dentro de otra que evalúa sus parámetros de forma estándar, que es justamente el caso de tu pregunta, `agrupar()` evalúa el parámetro `col` de manera estándar, deberías transformar el vector de caracteres recibido, en nombre de columnas tal como lo estaría necesitando `group_by()`, esa una forma, pero bastante compleja sobre todo de entender.

Sin embargo, hay una alternativa más fácil ya que `dplyr` posee también, en algunos casos, versiones de las rutinas tradicionales, pero que evalúan los parámetros recibidos de forma estándar. Tal es el caso de [`group_by_at()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_by_all.html) dónde `.vars` puede ser un vector de caracteres:

```
agrupar <- function(columnas) {
  
  d1 %>%  
    group_by_at(columnas) %>% 
    summarise(n = n())
}

agrupar(c("Modelo","Color"))
agrupar(c("Modelo"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Esto podría funcionar

```
agrupar <- function(...){    # En ... puedo pasar un número arbitrario de argumentos.

  grupos <- enquos(...)  #Tomo los ... y los hago una quotation
  d1 %>%  
    group_by(!!!grupos) %>%  #El !!! "abre" la quotation a nombres, que es lo que group_by necesita
    summarise(n= n())
  
}

agrupar(carb, gear)  #Los argumentos tienen que ir como nombres, no cadenas de caracteres.
```